# Why is there a "clear" class right before footer?

Tags: html, css

I have recently been modifying a template from Blogofile, which is written in HTML 5.

When I looked at the generated page, there is a

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

box in the html source code right before footer. What does this mean? How do I set CSS accordingly?

The CSS is here: https://github.com/EnigmaCurry/blogofile_blog/blob/master/blogofile_blog/site_src/themes/theme1/style.css

Comment: Did you look-up the definition of `.clear`?

Comment: It's a so-called _clearfix_. Google that. ;)

Comment: What does the CSS for this class look like?  Usually something like this is used to apply a `clear` property in the CSS to ensure that elements draw below whatever came before it.

Comment: @Dai I don't know. This is not defined in the demonstrating CSS.

Comment: I think we need to see the CSS or at least have links to it.  In particular, generic `div` CSS will apply to this class, as well as ancestral and class-specific CSS.  If none of these apply or modify the `float` and `clear` properties of a `div.clear` then use the default "box" rules for a `div`...

Comment: @abiessu The CSS is here: https://github.com/EnigmaCurry/blogofile_blog/blob/master/blogofile_blog/site_src/themes/theme1/style.css

Comment: Based on that CSS, and assuming there is nothing in the HTML file specifying further CSS, we can assume default HTML rules for this `div`, namely that the default is to have `clear: both;` applied to it (thus the class name), which means that there can be nothing "floating" horizontally to the left or right of it; other normally-positioned elements must appear vertically above or below this block within the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, as mentioned by others, it is a class carrying the css values:

```
.clear{clear: both;}
```

in order to prevent any more page elements from extending into the footer element. It is a quick and easy way of making sure that pages with columns of varying heights don't cause the footer to render oddly, by possibly setting its top position at the end of a shorter column.

In many cases it is not necessary, but if you are using best-practice standards it is a good idea to use, if you are floating page elements left and right. It functions with page elements similar to the way a horizontal rule works with text, to ensure proper and complete sepperation.

Answer (score 1):

A class in HTML means that in order to set attributes to it in CSS, you simply need to add a period in front of it.

For example, the **CSS** code of that html code may be:

```
.clear {
    height: 50px;
    width: 25px;
}
```

Also, if you, as suggested by *abiessu*, are attempting to add the CSS `clear: both;` attribute to the div to prevent anything from floating to the left or right of this div, you can use this **CSS** code:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Well answered for generic CSS.  Now, can you speak to the specifics of why there is a class named `clear` and how it is used?

Comment: Thank you.  I named the class clear because that was the name of the class in the proposed question.  For how it is used, you set the class in html as shown in the question and connect the two documents (html and css) by inserting a connection to the css document in the head of the html code.

Comment: This question is deeper than having a class named `clear`... it could be named `blah` and have the same effect, but there is a reason it is named `clear` and I wonder if you know why and can expand your answer to talk about it...

Comment: Are you referring to setting the background color to transparent?

Comment: No, see my comment on the question for further info.  `clear` does not relate to color, rather it has to do with positioning and page flow.

Comment: I see now.  I updated the answer.